# What is canonical grasp?

Tags: robotic-arm, manipulator, theory

What is a canonical grasp and how is it different from normal/other grasp? I've searched through internet and forums but haven't found any answers.

Comment: i am not an expert in robotics ... this may help ... https://www.lyrn.ai/2018/12/30/sim2real-using-simulation-to-train-real-life-grasping-robots/ ... from reading that page, it seems to me that *canonical grasp* may be an incorrect term, and may be the reason why your search has not yielded results